Restriction of vector bundle in case of non empty boundary
Let E and M be manifolds with boundary where E is a vector bundle over M. Consider the restriction of the vector bundle E  to a vector bundle E_s over an embedded submanifold with boundary S of M. Is it correct to state that E_s is an embedded submanifold with boundary of E?
I know this is true if we replace "with boundary" with "without boundary".
Here the notation comes from J.Lee's book "An introduction to smooth manifold", pag. 225.

What have you tried? Where do you get stuck?
